# Magento 2.2.3 upgrade

Tags: magento2, magento2.2

please I made a test site to try to upgrade my Magento 2.2.3, but until now I haven't succeeded at all. I could understand if I have to stop at 2.2 or go directly to 2.3, and if possible how to proceed too. I can not understand and I can not find info, thank you very much.

for example, if I had to step by step which version do I go to? do i change the php version first?

---

i have community edition i'ts same? and my problem is the PHP version, because now i have 7.1, i want now after update magento i update PHP or befor
thanks

Answer (score 1):

Refer to the [official step-by-step guide](https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/upgrade-guide/implementation/perform-upgrade.html) for detailed instructions.

However, here are some crucial steps and tips to consider:

1. **Backup First:** Always take a backup of both the codebase and the database.
2. **Maintenance Mode:** Activate the maintenance mode to ensure there's no interference during the upgrade.
3. **Environment Setup:** Review and set up the appropriate environment. This includes ensuring you have the compatible PHP version, database, and other necessary components. Install everything you need based on the Magento version you're moving to.
4. **Third-party Modules:** Deactivate and remove any third-party modules that aren't compatible with your new Magento version (*you must uninstall it correctly on the old Magento version before you move*). Always verify module compatibility on the respective vendor's site. Sometimes, finding an updated version can be challenging, so it's vital to verify this in advance.
5. **Follow the Official Guide:** Execute the commands from the official guide sequentially. If you encounter any roadblocks, then consider alternate solutions.
6. **Before you start working, brew yourself a lot of coffee :)** Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Hi from you can upgrade any version of magento 2 directly using below steps

```
composer require magento/composer-root-update-plugin=~1.0 --no-update
composer update --ignore-platform-reqs
cp composer.json composer.json.bak
composer remove magento/product-enterprise-edition --no-update
composer require magento/product-enterprise-edition 2.4.1 --no-update
composer update --ignore-platform-reqs
```